# how to get cluster membership as data in kcca method?

Tags: r, cluster-analysis

I am using `kcca` to fit k median clustering. I have used the following syntax:

```
kcca.out1_1 <- kcca(clusterdata1_1, k=5, family=kccaFamily("kmedians"), save.data=TRUE)
```

Now I want the cluster membership as a data frame or vector so that I can use them in my dataset to do further data analysis.

Any sort of help would be highly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Try the `clusters` function:

```
clusters(kcca.out1_1)
```

---

From the help page:

```
## S4 method for signature 'flexclust, ANY':
clusters(object, newdata, ...)
```

`clusters` can be used on any object of class `flexclust` and returns the cluster memberships of the training data.

```
## S4 method for signature 'kccasimple':
predict(object, newdata, ...)
```

`predict` can be used only on objects of class `kcca` (which inherit from `flexclust`). If no `newdata` argument is specified, the function is identical to `clusters`, if `newdata` is specified, then cluster memberships for the new data are predicted. `clusters(object, newdata, ...)` is an alias for `predict(object, newdata, ...)`.